# Why is the Puppet agent not recognising environments?

Tags: puppet

I have configured dynamic environments in `puppet.conf` such as:

```
 modulepath = $confdir/environments/$environment/modules
 manifest = $confdir/environments/$environment/site/manifests/site.pp
 environmentpath = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments
```

My `environments` dir has the environments along with `manifest/site.pp` file and `modules` dir.

However when I run the agent `sudo puppet agent --test --environment=test`
I get the following error (I have not set the environment to `production` in the agent's `puppet.conf` file):

`Warning: Local environment: "test" doesn't match server specified node environment "production", switching agent to "production".`

It only applies the production environment's modules.

I am using puppet enterprise 3.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out because I was using the PE version, the node was auto-classified to the `production` environment, hence the problem. Changing the environment to `agent-specified` in the classification section worked.

Comment: More to the point: This is specific to using an External Node Classifier, which is what PE does through Puppet Dashboard. You can configure open source Puppet to use an ENC as well. The same restrictions apply then.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. :) I went to `Node > Classification > Rules` (Tab), and then selected `agent_specified_environment` and entered the environment name that i created. Commit the change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an explanation but I have 3.73 and use environment without issues. My `puppet.conf` file contains: `environmentpath=$confdir/environments` but does not contain a `manifest` or `modulepath` entry.

The module and manifest path are defined in an `environment.conf` at the root of the environment directory:

```
manifest = manifests/
modulepath = modules:site
```

As for the agent, I modified the `puppet.conf` on the node to specify the environment but the parameter as you put it should work (it does clearly tell the agent which environment to use as per the error you supplied).

Comment: Thanks. I have essentially done the same thing except that its in the global `puppet.conf` file. A similar setup works in the OS version so I'm wondering if the PE version does something different.

Comment: @aspiringCodeArtisan - that could be possibly a difference, I use the open source version.